# What is the accuracy on country level of GeoLite2 Country DB?

Tags: geolocation, geoip, maxmind, ip-geolocation, geolite2

What is the accuracy on the country level of GeoLite2 Country DB? Also, is there any data about the accuracy on the country level for all different DBs(including both paid & free)available in the market?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the accuracy data in their web site.

GeoIP2 Accuracy:
https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-city-database-accuracy

IP2Location Accuracy:
https://www.ip2location.com/data-accuracy

Comment: That information is for their paid, geoip2 service.  The question is regarding the free, geolite2 database.